# recursively find max and min in array pseudo code

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

I'd like to know if this pseudo code finds the min and max values of the array recursively and properly.

```
MinMax(A, max, min)
if (|A| == 1)
    if (max < A[1])
        max = A[1]
    if (min > A[1])
        min = A[1]
    return A
Aleft = MinMax(l, max, min)
Aright = MinMax(r, max, min)
Aall = Merge(Aleft, Aright)
return min,max
```

Is it ok?

Comment: The number of arguments in the recursive calls does not match the signature in the first line.

Comment: The simplest (but dangerous in practice) is linear recursion: the min item of an array is either the first item of the array or a min item of the rest part of the array (you might also want to use the last item instead of the first one). Similary for max item.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not OK.

l and r are used but not defined.
the two returns are different
what does merge do?

perhaps you mean

```
MinMax(A, max, min)
    if (|A| == 1)
        if (max < A[1])
            max = A[1]
        if (min > A[1])
            min = A[1]
        return (min,max)
    mid=|A|/2
    l=A[:mib-1]
    r=A[mid:]
    (min,max) = MinMax(l, max, min)
    (min,max) = MinMax(r, max, min)
    return (min,max)
```

but the merge business suggests you may be looking for a multithreadable solution.

```
MinMax(A, max, min)
    if (|A| == 1)
        if (max < A[1])
            max = A[1]
        if (min > A[1])
            min = A[1]
        return (min,max)
    mid=|A|/2
    l=A[:mib-1]
    r=A[mid:]
    (lmin,lmax) = MinMax(l, max, min)
    (rmin,rmax) = MinMax(r, max, min)
    if lmin < rmin 
        rmin=lmin
    if lmax > rmax
        rmax=lmax
    return (rmin,rmax)
```